# Imagging Ram in Android 5.1.1 with mem

Tags: memory

I want to perform imaging Android RAM. But I got this error.

```
$ dev/mem 4561 | dev/mem/nc -l -p 6666
sh: dev/mem: can't execute: Permission denied
sh: dev/mem/nc: not found
```

My devices running Android 5.1.1. In the dev directory with mem.

Comment: Please show us what commands you are running when you get the error.

Comment: # dev/mem 4561 | dev/mem/nc -l -p 6666
sh: dev/mem: can't execute: Permission denied
sh: dev/mem/nc: not found

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant `/dev/mem` instead of `dev/mem`? That beginning slash is important.